# Native php function to turn single dimensional array into two dimensional

Tags: php

I want to turn plain array into two dimensional array. I can do it with a code below but is there native PHP function to handle it. I went through the manual and wen but didn't see anything.

Thanks

`$array = array('a', 'b');`

Should be converted into:

`$array = array('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'b');`

I don't want to use this if there is a simple function:

```
foreach($array as &$value)
{
    $new[$value] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine), which combines (suprisingly enough) an array of keys and an array of values into a single array.

```
$array = array_combine($array, $array);
```

Comment: @TerrySeidler this is probably the first time *ever* that I have beaten anyone to an answer: I generally type *far* too slowly! *\*little victory dance\**

Comment: Never thought about it! 10 minutes to accept your answer. Thank